# How can I solve "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null" on component vue?

Tags: vue.js, slider, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3" v-for="item in items">
            <!-- this is images  slider -->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        mounted() {
            this.getTopLeague([{league_id: this.leagueId}]) // this is ajax if load first
            setTimeout( function(){ 
                $('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 4, infinite: false});
            }  , 10000 ); // I set 10 seconds for the finished ajax process just started the slider
        },
        ...
        methods: {
            changeLeague(leagueId) {
                this.getTopLeague([{league_id: leagueId}]) // this is ajax if a link clicked    
                setTimeout( function(){ 
                    $('.slick').slick({slidesToShow: 4, infinite: false});
                }  , 10000 );  //I set 10 seconds for the finished ajax process just started the slider
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null
>       at jQuery.fn.init.a.fn.slick

The error occurs after 10 second or ajax process finished

I set the slider to run after 10 seconds because if the ajax process has not finished there is an error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Plz use a  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) !

Comment: take care of the scope inside setTimeout...and yes, use a fiddle if you want people to debug...

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what you are doing, but I guess you mean that an error will be thrown if ajax call won't finishes in 10 seconds, don't you? If so, you should consider that _AJAX_ calls run **asynchronously** and the dependent block of code should be written in callback function (e.g. `.done()` if using _jQuery_ or `.then()` if _axios_ ...).

Comment: I had solve it. Use  : `$('.slick').not('.slick-initialized').slick({slidesToShow: 3, infinite: false});` like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255934/why-the-slider-does-not-work-when-i-click-another-tab-on-vue-component